# Emacs Function which eliminates all indentation

Tags: emacs

Is there an emacs function which eliminates all indentation in a region (i.e. all whitespace before the first non-whitespace character)?

If not, what snippet of code should I add to my .emacs to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `C-u -1000 M-x indent-code-rigidly RET`.

Answer (score 5):

```el
(defun my-delete-indentation (start end)
  "Delete all leading whitespace within the current region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (replace-regexp "^[[:space:]]+" "" nil start end))
```

(n.b. there is a `delete-indentation` function in Emacs, but it does something rather different to this.)